How to make HTMLLabel() work in Pyglet 2.0?
The section "Displaying text" of the official pyglet document (https://pyglet.readthedocs.io/en/latest/programming_guide/text.html), gives an example of how to use HTMLLabel(). The example works in pyglet 1.5.28 but not in pyglet 2.0.15. Weirdly enough, HTMLLabel() does not raise an error --e.g. "pyglet.text has no method HTMLLabel()" (or something similar) as it is usually the case-- i.e. it is accepted by v2.0, only nothing is shown in the pyglet window.
Below is a simple but fully workable code in which I added whatever is needed to run that example:
import pyglet
from pyglet.gl import *

window = pyglet.window.Window(200,200)
glClearColor(1, 1, 1, 1)

# The following 4 lines are copy-pasted from the document 
label = pyglet.text.HTMLLabel(
    '<font face="Times New Roman" size="4">Hello, <i>world</i></font>',
    x=window.width//2, y=window.height//2,
    anchor_x='center', anchor_y='center')

@window.event
def on_draw():
  window.clear()
  label.draw()

pyglet.app.run()

Here's the output produced by v1.15:

Running the same code with v2.0 shows an empty window.
I have searched the Web extensively but could not find not a solution, but even what is the problem. Not even near.
So, I hope that someone in here does have a solution for using HTML text as a label (or in any other way) in v2.0.

This looks like a bug in pyglet, introduced in version 2.0.12.
If you downgrade to version 2.0.10, your code will display the HTML text:
pip install --force-reinstall -v "pyglet==2.0.10"
You should create a bug report.

Thanks.  I'm running v.2.0.15. I have already installed 1.5.28 in another installation in order to run older pyglet programs. And I have enough with pyglet version incompatibilities. The story never ends. Great S/W, but its developer(s) is/are insane,
